# How to set up .yarnrc.yml for multiple private npm packages with different registry servers, but the same scope?

Tags: node.js, yarn-v2

I've seen multiple similar questions, but none gives the full answer. I'm trying to migrate my project to Yarn v4. I have several private npm packages hosted on GitLab. They have different registry server addresses, but the same scope. The previous setup with `.npmrc` looked like this:

```
@my-company:registry=https://gitlab.com/api/api-version/projects/project-id-1/packages/npm/
//gitlab.com/api/api-version/projects/project-id-1/packages/npm/:_authToken=${auth-token}

@my-company:registry=https://gitlab.com/api/api-version/projects/project-id-2/packages/npm/
//gitlab.com/api/api-version/projects/project-id-2/packages/npm/:_authToken=${auth-token}

@my-company:registry=https://gitlab.com/api/api-version/projects/project-id-3/packages/npm/
//gitlab.com/api/api-version/projects/project-id-3/packages/npm/:_authToken=${auth-token}
```

Where my packages have names: `@my-company/package1`, `@my-company/package2` and `@my-company/package3`.

By trial and error I've found that everything works with one package `@my-company/package1`, when my `.yarnrc.yml` looks like this:

```yaml
nodeLinker: node-modules

npmScopes:
  my-company:
    npmAlwaysAuth: true
    npmAuthToken: ${auth-token}
    npmRegistryServer: "https://gitlab.com/api/api-version/projects/project-id-1/packages/npm/"

yarnPath: .yarn/releases/yarn-4.1.1.cjs
```

But I can't find a way to set different `npmRegistryServer` for different packages as `@my-company/package2` and `@my-company/package3` require different URL. What is a proper way to config `.yarnrc.yml`?